# statement.executeQuery in oracle is very slow & inconsistent

Tags: java, oracle, performance, web-services

When I try to pull oracle data using java webservice , the time taken to execute the query is so inconsistent.

To pull 5000 records, executeQuery takes 8 mins , some times the same query executes in 20 seconds.I was thinking this is due to cache. But few instances the first time execution is very fast. I have added the below code ,but still it is inconsistent.

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                       ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
statement.setFetchSize(5000);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

The database is in different server. When I use sql developer to execute the query it took only 20 seconds and it is consistent.

I am using oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver. can anyone help me how to troubleshoot the issue/better way to implement java webservice to pull data?

Comment: Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

Comment: Please don't make "additions" to the question in comments. Instead, use the `edit` button (underneath the tags) to edit your question. I've done it this time - please check that I got it right and re-edit if needed. Thanks.

Comment: It's rather difficult to figure out what the issue might be, given that the SELECT statement isn't shown. Could you please edit the question and include the SELECT, along with the setting of parameters, etc? As a general rule you need to include all the code related to an issue rather than just a couple of statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Query performance can change dramatically if the query plan is developed based on one parameter value, and then a different value is supplied for which the existing plan is a poor choice. Or this may be an indication that the table statistics are stale. You can update the statistics for your table by running something like:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('YOURSCHEMA', 'YOURTABLE');
END;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: I am getting read time out error when I ran a simple query in sql developer . Looks like network connectivity is not good enough. How can I confirm this?

Comment: This is a completely different question, and one I'm not able to help with. You might try asking it on dba.stackexchange.com. Best of luck.